Do moving cars hurt flies?
Say a car where to move at highway speeds and a small insect such as a fly where to come across its path. Would the fly get hit with the same force as if it were a human, or will the fly get swept across by the wind?

Have you never been in car when an insect hit the windshield? They splat.

The question is interesting insofar as there does seem to be a complex counterplay between the air turbulence that surrounds a car as it goes, and the relative closing speed of the car on the insect with respect to that air flow.

I would answer this with an answer about how the aerodynamics of the car changes how a fly otherwise hovering might get moved out of the way, but in reality, I know from experience that my car's windshield is an insectoid graveyard ...

The fact that flies splat on windshields doesn't answer the question here.

@controlgroup I though the same would happen, That the fly would be small enough to be swept away by the cars aerodynamics. Maybe Il run some simulations trying different speeds and car shapes once I learn how

@Linkin Just as important is the insect's velocity (and in theory its mass, but more negligible). If both car and insect are rushing towards one another in a head to head manner the probability of said "splat" greatly increases ;) A dragonfly for example can reach speeds of up to ~50km/h!!

An insect in front of a car will be swept aside if the force from the airflow around the car is strong enough to push it laterally around the car. If it is not strong enough, the insect will go through the boundary layer and likely splat.
The boundary layer has a thickness that declines with the Reynolds number, but it pretty thin (for 30 km/h Re=8816, making it a few mm), so we can ignore it. The region where the air changes flow around the car is clearly less than a meter thick. So if the car travels at speed $v$, that air needs to move about $L\approx 1$ meter to the side over time $1/v$, requiring an acceleration on the order of $a\sim 2Lv^2$. A tiny insect just following the air will just be swept aside.
This is determined by the Stokes number, the ratio of slowing time due to drag on the insect times the car velocity to the obstacle size L; $St=2r^2\rho v/9\mu L$. If this is much greater than 1 the insect will not follow a streamline and will likely collide.
I have no great source on insect drag coefficients, but plugging in a 1 cm insect I get for a 30 km/h car a $St \sim 10^4$ , and it is pretty obvious that it is not hard to increase $v$ so a previously unscathed bug gets hit. Overall, this seems to fit with empirical data on insect collisions, that suggest that bigger insects are much more at risk.

Whatever force the fly or human experiences due to collision with the car will be equal and opposite to the force that the car experiences per Newton’s third law. The magnitude of the force that the fly or human experiences will equal its rate of change in momentum, per Newton’s second law.
If the fly is swept away by the wind avoiding direct contact with the car it will still undergo a rate of change in momentum, but it would be far less than if it collided with the car, allowing it to survive. Direct collision with the car, on the other hand, would smash the fly as @march pointed out.
Hope this helps.

The fly usually gets a free ride on your car’s breeze, but if it is unlucky enough to hit the car, it’s lights out.Nature is not very kind in this case!
The force exerted during a collision can be determined using:
$$
F = \frac{{\Delta p}}{\Delta t}=\frac{m \cdot \Delta v}{\Delta t}
$$
1. Fly's Case:

Mass of the fly, $ m_{\text{fly}} = 10^{-6} kg $ (1 milligram).
Speed of the car, $ v = 30 m/s $ (about 108 km/h ).
Collision time, $ \Delta t = 0.001 s$.

Then the force on the fly is:
$$
F_{\text{fly}} = \frac{(10^{-6} kg) (30 m/s)}{0.001 s}=  0.03 N
$$
2. Human's Case:

Mass of the human, $ m_{\text{human}}= 70 kg $.
Speed of the car same as the fly’s case.
Collision time,$ \Delta t= 0.1 s $ (longer than for the fly due to cushioning effects due to the differences in mass, structural properties,and how energy is absorbed and dissipated during the impact.).

The force on the human is:
$$
F_{\text{human}}= \frac{(70 kg) (30 \, \text{m/s})}{0.1 s} =  21000 N
$$
Although this is a huge force compared to what a fly would feel,it is still deadly for the fly due to its small mass.The fly gets squashed, and the human gets badly injured.

-1: Where do you get those collision times from?

I approximated the collision response times for humans based on general estimations found through Google search regarding "collision time of human biomechanical response to impact."  For flyers, I based my estimates on similar studies for insects, such as the one described in this article: Link.
These are rough approximations, but they should provide a general sense of the relative forces. If you have more accurate data or sources, I'd be happy to update the estimates. @SebastianRiese

When insect hits the wind shield of the car, it exerts a force on wind shield and according to Newton's third law wind shield will exert equal force on the insect but in opposite direction. Thus, both the car and insect experienced the same force.
According to conservation of momentum, during collision, the total momentum of the system remains conserved. It means the change in momentum of the car should be equal and opposite to that of the insect. Since the momentum is the product of mass and velocity of the body, the insect having smaller mass will suffer greater change in velocity resulting in greater injuries or even death. Whereas car having very large mass will suffer very small change in velocity.
The insect gets stuck and moves as one single body with the car
When the insect collides with the car, it gets stuck and moves as one single body, so there is no external force applied to them and there will be no change in momentum.
The force of impact from the collision splatters the insect over the windshield.
Hope that answers your question. Also, nice observation by @march . That is a clear proof.
